# App Crashes in iOS 7 due to EXC_BAD_ACCESS INVALID ADDRESS in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, crash-reports

I have a very strange issue. I have an app that consists of a `UITableView` as the home screen. The same works fine in iOS 9 & 10 , but crashes in iOS 7 saying `EXC_BAD_ACCESS INVALID ADDRESS AT KERN`.

I am posting the code of the `UIViewController`, and for logging let me tell that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method gets called `numberofsections` times (Which I want it to ) and right after that , the app crashes before executing the `ViewDidAppear` method. Here's my code:

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

#include "DetailsViewController.h"
#include "AppCatalogViewController.h"
#include "SupportViewController.h"
#include "documentviewer.h"
#include "AgentUpgradeHandler.h"
 #include "Persistence.h"
#include "HttpWrapper.h"
#include "EnrollmentProcessConstants.h"

#include "NoDocumentViewController.h"
#include "documentViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"titlestring", nil);
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber)<=NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = APP_ACCENT_COLOR;
} else {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = APP_ACCENT_COLOR;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    [UIColor whiteColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,nil];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;
}
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName :[UIColor whiteColor]}];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"mdm.agent.common.home", nil);
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"mdm.agent.common.home", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
[button setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = button;
Persistence *persist = [[Persistence alloc]init];
NSLog(@"The version saved is :%ld and comp value is %d",(long)[[persist getObject:@"Version"]integerValue],([[persist getObject:@"Version"]integerValue]<AGENTVERSIONCODE));

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:DISABLED forKey:SEARCHON];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

if ([persist getObject:@"Version"]==NULL||[[persist getObject:@"Version"]integerValue]<AGENTVERSIONCODE) {
    [self sendUpgrade];
    [persist setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",AGENTVERSIONCODE] forKey:@"Version"];
}
if((![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] || ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)) && ([[persist getObject:LOCATION_SERVICES] intValue] == 1)) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Location Permission Denied"
                                                    message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}

 - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:YES];
 self.navigationController.delegate = nil;

Persistence *persist = [[Persistence alloc]init];
NSString *needsupgrade = [persist getObject:@"NeedsUpgrade"];
if ([needsupgrade isEqual:@"true"]) {
    [self showUpgradeMessage];
}
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSLog(@"viewWillAppearcalled");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
self.navigationController.delegate = nil;
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if( cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectionColor.backgroundColor = APP_ACCENT_COLOR;
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
if(indexPath.section==0) {

    cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"title1", nil);

}
if (indexPath.section==1) {

    cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"title2", nil);

}
if (indexPath.section==2) {

    cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"title3", nil);
}
if (indexPath.section==3) {

    cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"tite4", nil);
}

 return cell;
}

@end
```

link to download stacktrace :
http://www.filedropper.com/mdmiosagent

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need breakpoint for Exception http://take.ms/HCF3C and we see in what line is made bad news.

Comment: Post the stack trace you are getting in the log

Comment: i am unable to post the stack trace because of the body size restriction

Comment: Desymbolicate the crash log . It contain memory stack trace